# Move library of documents with version numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, version-history

We have a library in SharePoint where we use versioning. We also insert the version number from SharePoint to a label in the header in Word. It works well.
See the method here: https://collab365.community/forum/topics/how-to-automatically-insert-the-document-version-from-sp-in-a/

Now we want to move the library to a site in a different site collection. There are several methods to do this. 
You can save the library with the document as a template that you saved as file and upload to the other site. 
You can use Windows PowerShell. 
You can use a third-party product such as Share-gate.

The versioning is on in the new library.

The problem with them all is that the version number in the documenten doesn't come with the label in a proper manner. The version number is not included in the document correctly. Either it turn up like “{_UIVersionString}” or it goes to back to the first number (1 or 0.1) or it goes down a version so that the version number 5 becomes 4, 4 becomes 3 and so on. The last example was with Share-gate.

Does anyone know of a method or tool for moving a library of documents that have the version number in labels that managed to move the documents while maintaining the version number of the documents?